# How do I write a loop in a gdb script?

Tags: fortran, gdb

After adapting this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20481815/how-to-loop-in-a-gdb-script-till-program-is-finished), I wrote the following loop to simply print an array in gdb in a script called "gdb_script.gs". What am I doing wrong?

```
set $end=64  
while ($i<$end)
   print $i
   print volfrac($i, :, 1)
   set $i=$i+1
end
```

where volfrac(:,:,:) is a fortran array. I am getting the error:

```
 gdb_script.gs:14: Error in sourced command file:
 A syntax error in expression, near `<$end)'.
```

Comment: Don't you want to initialize `$i` before comparing it to anything?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The other answer totally missed the point. The hint was the reported error:

```
    gdb_script.gs:14: Error in sourced command file:
    A syntax error in expression, near `<$end)'.
```

The hint is `<$end)`, which means there is a syntax error in the while statement. By experimenting further, I am posting my results if others need it in the future:

```
 set $ipx=0
 set $end=32

 while ($ipx .lt. 32)
     print $ipx
     print ro($ipx, 1)
     set $ipx=$ipx+1
 end
```

The key was to use the fortran syntax for comparison ($ipx .lt. 32) instead of the usual "c" syntax ($ipx < 32).

Answer (score 4):

GDB newbies (as myself) should know that the accepted answer does not work unless you remove the blank between `while` and the first brace.

Also, the `.lt.` syntax probably works only for Fortran (https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Fortran.html). As the title of the question is not formulated specifically toward Fortran developers, the accepted answer can be misleading.

Comment: You should perhaps mention the GDB version you used.

Comment: Not in title but the text of the question does mention Fortran. Also when I was posting the question, I did not know gdb syntax depends on the language being debugged.

Comment: @Armali, I am using GDB 7.7.1.

Answer (score 3):

```
set $i = 0
p $i++
```

keep pressing **Enter** this is one of the easiest logic I found

Comment: Irrelevant. You didn't read the question. I am trying to print an big Fortran array. If the array is 512x512x4 are you willing to press enter  262144x4 times ? See accepted answer

Comment: this was helpful for my small use case, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since voltrac() is an array, then I think it is a syntax error as show in your output - it should be "print volfrac[]" instead.

**Below I showed you the step by step in detail for a C program (since you are working with gdb, and gdb only worked with ELF file, and so it is the same here - gdb + ELF file for C)**:

> ```
> (gdb) run
> Starting program: /home/tthtlc/a.out 
>
> Breakpoint 1, main () at main.c:5
> 5 main(){
> ```

First I step through a few times and noticed my assignment:

> ```
> (gdb) s
> 8     for(i=0;i<10;i++)
> (gdb) 
> 9     for(j=0;j<10;j++)
> (gdb) 
> 10        for(k=0;k<10;k++) {
> (gdb) 
> **11      volfrac[i][j][k]=0xdeadbeef;**
> (gdb)
> ```

Now is the printing out (and notice the different ways of printing the array):

> ```
> (gdb) print /x volfrac[0][0][0]
> $5 = 0xdeadbeef
> (gdb) print /x volfrac[0][0]
> $6 = {0xdeadbeef, 0xdeadbeef, 0xdeadbeef, 0xdeadbeef, 0xdeadbeef, 0xdeadbeef, 
>   0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}
> (gdb) print /x volfrac[0]
> $7 = {{0xdeadbeef, 0xdeadbeef, 0xdeadbeef, 0xdeadbeef, 0xdeadbeef, 0xdeadbeef, 
> (gdb) print /x volfrac
> $8 = {{{0xdeadbeef, 0xdeadbeef, 0xdeadbeef, 0xdeadbeef, 0xdeadbeef, 
>       0xdeadbeef, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 
> (gdb) print /x volfrac(0,0,0)
> Invalid data type for function to be called.
> ```

Comment: volfrac  is a fortran array